# How to combine specific letters and numbers from different cells in Excel?

Tags: excel, cells

I have 3 names that I want to combine to create something unique - I've used "CONCATENATE", but to no avail.

Example:

1. Paper (will always be different)
2. 000001 (This will be sequential, the next row will have 000002)
3. Plastic (will always be different)

Essentially I want to input all three items in different cells and have the fourth cell output the following:

**Pa000001Pl**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With values in **A1**, **B1**, and **C1**, in another cell enter:

```
=LEFT(A1,2)&TEXT(B1,"00000")&LEFT(C1,2)
```

[image]

This is needed to preserve the leading zeros **if those leading zeros are the result of formatting cell B1**

Answer (score 1):

Using `&` between objects is an alternative way to concatenate in excel:

```
=LEFT(A1,2) & B1 & LEFT(C1,2)
```

See http://fiveminutelessons.com/learn-microsoft-excel/extract-text-cell-excel for info on how to extract text from cells. (Examples: `LEFT()`, `RIGHT()`, `MID()`,`FIND()`.

See https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Combine-the-contents-of-multiple-cells-3a86c317-6b91-4f1d-8781-203320aefdce for info on how to combine text from cells.

If you want to keep the 00000's in the number you need to make sure to format the cells containing the numbers as `Text`.

You could do this using the `TEXT()` function on the fly:

```
=LEFT(A1,2) & TEXT(B1,"000000") & LEFT(C1,2)
```

The six 0's tell Excel to create a number 6 digits long and replace any 0 with a non-zero number from your cell. So if **B1** is 1, `TEXT(B1,"000000")` will convert it to 000001. If **B11** is 11, `TEXT(B11,"000000")` will convert it to 000011.

If you instead want to ensure that the same number of 0's remain in front of your non-zero numbers, you could use the `CONCATENATE()` function:

```
=LEFT(A1,2) & CONCATENATE(B1,"00000") & LEFT(C1,2)
```

This would always insert five 0's in front of whatever number is listed in **B1**.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your values are in the 2nd Row

```
=LEFT(A2,2) & B2 & LEFT(C2,2)
```

Comment: Hello rwilson - thank you, but the input came out as Pa1Pl - I would like to keep the 5 zeros so it comes out as Pa000001Pl